# Loading a YouTube video using the API

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

This is killing me. I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5w9Xn/1/) with my code. Nothing fancy, just trying to load a YouTube video.

Am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to subscribe the eventlistener first.

You could try

```
ytplayer.addEventListener("**onPlayerReady**", "onYouTubePlayerReady");
```

Be sure the **onPLayerReady** is the correct event name, i'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
ytplayer = loadVideoById('Ahg6qcgoay4', 0,'medium');
```

Should be this:

```
ytplayer.loadVideoById('Ahg6qcgoay4', 0,'medium');
```

`loadVideoById` is a method of the player.  You should have seen a "loadVideoById is not defined" error when you tried to run this.

A simpler way to get it working is to include the video id in the url you are loading:

```
var videoID = 'Ahg6qcgoay4';
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + "?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1", ...
```